# How to typeset an isomorphism symbol ($\simeq$) with a long bar

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, stacking-symbols

Is there any way to typeset in LaTeX a `\simeq` with a longer bar, or equivalently  `\stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow}` without the arrowhead?

Answer (score 7):

The following constructs the math symbol `\isomorphism` similar to `\simeq`, but with a longer line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isomorphism}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@isomorphism{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@isomorphism}[2]{%
  % Calculate the amount of moving \sim up as in \simeq
  \sbox0{$#1\simeq$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\sim$}%
  \dimen@=\ht0 %
  \advance\dimen@ by -\ht2 %
  %
  % Compose the two symbols
  \sbox0{%
    \lower1.9\dimen@\hbox{%
      $\m@th#1\relbar\isomorphism@joinrel\relbar$%
    }%
  }%
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{%
      \hfill\raise\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sim$}\hfill
    }%
  }%
  \copy0 %
}
\newcommand*{\isomorphism@joinrel}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-3.4mu %
    \mkern-1mu %
    \nonscript\mkern1mu %
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ A \isomorphism B \simeq C = D \sim E \]
\[ A \isomorphism B^{C \isomorphism D^{E \isomorphism F}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The line is constructed similar to `\longrightarrow`. There a line `\relbar` is joined a `\rightarrow`. The joining removes the side bearings, which means the glyphs can have white margins at the left and the right. LaTeX's `\joinrel` adds a negative space of `3mu` to move the relational symbols together. The test file uses the symbol in smaller math styles, there `-3mu` leaves a gap, therefore `\isomorphism@joinrel` is defined with customized settings (`-3.4mu` for `\displaystyle` and `\textstyle`, `-4.4mu` for `scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`).
- The symbol `\sim` is horizontally centered and set in the same math style and size. It is raised to the same height as aymbol `\simeq`.
- The vertical position of the line in `\simeq` is unhappily not available in TeX, therefore a guessed value is used (the shift of `\sim` multiplied by 1.9).
  If you want the line a little higher, then you can decrease the factor.
- `\mathpalette` is used to support the symbol in all math styles.
  Then the internal macro `\@isomorphism` gets the math style (`\displaystyle`, `\textstyle`, `\scriptstyle`, `\scriptscriptstyle`) as first argument. The second argument is not used and left empty.
- The measuring and glyph composing is done with many low level plain TeX macros
  for efficiency (and fun).
- `\m@th` sets `\mathsurround` to `0pt`. Usually the value is `0pt`, but if set, then the space that should surround math expressions should not occur inside a formula or math symbol.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343599/how-do-i-resolve-the-assertion-failed-popups. It works if the joining macro is redefined to take an argument (or if you give it something else to eat like an `x`). But I have no idea if this is wise .... It looks OK, but that's not much to go by. I've answered because it looks like a reasonable workaround, but ....

Answer (score 5):

I made this for our students how need a similar symbol for statistics

```
\newcommand\DistTo{\xrightarrow{
   \,\smash{\raisebox{-0.65ex}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle\sim}}}\,}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this still has the arrowhead!

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the question correctly. Though I think the placement is better than just using `\stackrel`, try combining them

Answer (score 3):

Combining some ideas from the answers of @Ian Thompson and @daleif, I think the following is pretty good.

```
\newcommand{\iso}{\ \raisebox{0.5ex}{\ensuremath{\stackrel{\sim}{\rule{16pt}{0.7pt}}}\ \,}}
```

[image]

Comment: the rule looks a bit too thick, and the `\sim` is a bit farther from the rule (or arrow) than one might like.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
A \stackrel{\displaystyle\sim}{\smash{\rule[1.5pt]{2em}{0.5pt}}} B
\]
\end{document}
```

Adjust the parameters as required. You can use `\raisebox` to raise the whole symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
A \raisebox{0pt}{$\stackrel{\displaystyle\sim}{\smash{\rule[1.5pt]{2em}{0.5pt}}}$} B
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  `\textwidth` is way too wide, about 16pt seems to be the same size as `\longrightarrow`.  However, the vertical position is too low.  See this picture: http://i.imgur.com/2qPcqUl.png

Comment: @Adeel --- I have edited my answer to allow vertical adjustment.