# How can I typeset \simeq-like arrow?

Tags: symbols

I need something like this:

[image: Example]

The closest I've managed to do looks like this, but it's definitely not very pretty:

[image]

How can I create this symbol? I can't seem to find it anywhere!

Comment: Do you want to improve the position of a tilda over an arrow or you want a kind of `\simeq` but with an arrow tip?

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\newcommand{\DistTo}{\xrightarrow{
   \,\smash{\raisebox{-0.65ex}{\ensuremath{\scriptstyle\sim}}}\,}}
\begin{document}
$\DistTo$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Now I remember taking, back then, this solution here on the website. My bad. Here's the link: [How to typeset an isomorphism symbol ($\simeq$) with a long bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121368/how-to-typeset-an-isomorphism-symbol-simeq-with-a-long-bar)

Comment: It would be better to leave only the packages strictly necessary for the example, or dependencies might be unclear to the non expert. Also `\smash` doesn't fully convince me.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the solution provided by Heiko Oberdiek to this question 
[The symbol for a map which is an isomorphism?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/the-symbol-for-a-map-which-is-an-isomorphism)

(which has been  enhanced by crf, egreg and david carlisle, only few days ago). [How do I resolve the assertion failed popups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343599/how-do-i-resolve-the-assertion-failed-popups)

Made slight modifications to my copy of the original for my own purposes: replaced the two `\relbar` macros with space and `\rightarrow` in the `\@isomorphism` command. Also gave the front-end command, `\isomorphism`,  an optional parameter in order to raise or lower the `\sim` symbol over the arrow to suit my needs.

Here is my copy of the Oberdiek's solution (with the minor modifications):

```
%%===================================================
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style = TeX,nabla = upright]{unicode-math}
%%
\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\setmathfont{FdSymbol Bold}[range={\ast}]       % bold asterisk symbol
%%===================================================
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\isomap}[1][3]{\mathrel{\raise 0.2ex\hbox{$\mathpalette\@isomap{#1}$}}}
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Calculate the distance of moving \sim up as in \simeq
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand*{\@isomap}[2]{%
    \sbox0{$#1\simeq$}%
    \sbox2{$#1\sim$}%
    \dimen@=\ht0%
    \advance\dimen@ by -\ht2%
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Compose the two symbols (\sim & \rightarrow)
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \sbox0{\lower#2\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\ \isomap@joinrel\rightarrow$}}%
    \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\hfill\raise\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sim$}\hfill}}%
    \box0%
}
%%
\newcommand*{\isomap@joinrel}{%
    \mathrel{\mkern-3.4mu\mkern-1mu\nonscript\mkern1mu\mkern0mu}%
}%
\makeatother
%%===================================================
\begin{document}
Test 1:\quad \( f\colon X \isomap Y \)
\bigskip%

Test 2:\quad \(\mu\colon H_q(X,Y)\isomap H_q(X/Y,\ast)\cong \widetilde{H}_q(X/Y)\)
\end{document}
%%===================================================
```

Also employed opentype fonts and raised the whole isomorphism map symbol a bit.