# How do I resolve the assertion failed popups?

Tags: errors, luatex

How do I resolve the "lualatex.exe assertion failed" popups? (I can on the Ignore tab to get out of it)

This beautiful solution, provided by Heiko Oberdiek, to the question *[How to typeset an isomorphism symbol ($\simeq$) with a long bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121368/how-to-typeset-an-isomorphism-symbol-simeq-with-a-long-bar)* works perfectly under pdflatex, xelatex and previous release of lualatex. But under the latest release of lualatex (texlive 2016) it causes a popup message of assertion failure. The popup seems to occur at the statement

```
  \sbox0{\lower1.9\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\relbar\isomorphism@joinrel\relbar$}}%
```

MWE:%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isomorphism}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@isomorphism{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@isomorphism}[2]{%
% Calculate the amount of moving \sim up as in \simeq
  \sbox0{$#1\simeq$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\sim$}%
  \dimen@=\ht0 %
  \advance\dimen@ by -\ht2 %
%----------------------------
% Compose the two symbols
%----------------------------
  \sbox0{%
    \lower1.9\dimen@\hbox{%
      $\m@th#1\relbar\isomorphism@joinrel\relbar$%
    }%
  }%
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{%
      \hfill\raise\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sim$}\hfill
    }%
  }%
  \copy0 %
}
\newcommand*{\isomorphism@joinrel}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-3.4mu %
    \mkern-1mu %
    \nonscript\mkern1mu %
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ A \isomorphism B^{C \isomorphism D^{E \isomorphism F}} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You say TeX Live, but you have tagged it MikTeX. Which are you using? If this is even relevant...

Comment: OK. It doesn't like `\noscript` + kern in `\mathrel{}` without something else. So giving it something else fixes the problem. Or, rather, works around the problem. This should probably be reported if it looks like a bug i.e. if the original code is kosher. (Which it should be given its author ;).)

Comment: It is clearly a bug in the binary -- you shouldn't get such a dialog even if you do nonsense in your document. But as it works in miktex (which has already luatex 1.0) it is possible that the bug has been resolved. @davidcarlisle could test it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get a core dump with luatex 1.01. I'll report of luatex list

Comment: Reported at http://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2016-December/006288.html

Comment: @Martin why add the windows tag? (it was all platforms as far as I can see)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Certainly Linux.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to work if the second symbol is consumed as an argument when joining it to the first. Tested with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (more-or-less current TeX Live 2016).

Just don't ask me to explain why LuaLaTeX doesn't like the original version, whereas pdfLaTeX does ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\isomorphism}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@isomorphism{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@isomorphism}[2]{%
% Calculate the amount of moving \sim up as in \simeq
  \sbox0{$#1\simeq$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\sim$}%
  \dimen@=\ht0 %
  \advance\dimen@ by -\ht2 %
%----------------------------
% Compose the two symbols
%----------------------------
  \sbox0{%
    \lower1.9\dimen@\hbox{%
      $\m@th#1\relbar\isomorphism@joinrel\relbar$%
    }%
  }%
  \rlap{%
    \hbox to \wd0{%
      \hfill\raise\dimen@\hbox{$\m@th#1\sim$}\hfill
    }%
  }%
  \copy0 %
}
\newcommand*{\isomorphism@joinrel}[1]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-3.4mu %
    \mkern-1mu %
    \nonscript\mkern1mu %
    #1
  }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ A \isomorphism B^{C \isomorphism D^{E \isomorphism F}} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: LuaTeX fix]

Answer (score 5):

This is fixed in revision 6174 of the luatex sources, committed today. It may take a while to appear in TeX distributions, the workarounds in  the other answers can be used until then.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently a bug in LuaTeX 0.95, which doesn't like a `\nonscript` item in that place.

You can solve it by reversing the order of the items:

```
\newcommand*{\isomorphism@joinrel}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mkern-3.4mu
    \nonscript\mkern1mu
    \mkern-1mu
  }%
}
```

A more general and safe workaround is to add a zero math kern after a `\nonscript` item that happens to fall at the end of a math list (or sublist), which seems to be the only case triggering the bug:

```
\nonscript\mkern<mudimen>\mkern0mu
```

or

```
\nonscript\mskip<muskip>\mkern0mu
```

Math kerns have no impact on the detection of math atoms and in the automatically inserted spaces between them.

Comment: Accept all the answers (cfr's and egreg's and David's permanent fix - looking forward to the new texlive/miktex distributions). Do employ the macro quite a lot in my developing document (at thirty different locations with a minor modification: replacing the two \relbar macros with a space and \rightarrow, respectively). Now the document compiles a lot faster than before... Excellent, CFR, David and egreg.